# Does the following hold as a conjecture for maximum gaps between prime numbers? and can it be proved?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, prime-gaps

Even though I used matrix related mathjax on the backend, the frontend is intended to be just a regular table.

$$\begin{matrix}
a&X&X:explanation
\\1&1
\\2&3
\\3&5
\\4&(6)&(X_2⋅2)=(3⋅2) 
\\5&7
\\6&(9),(10)&(X_2⋅3)=(3⋅3),(X_3⋅2)=(5⋅2)
\\7&11
\\8&(12)&(X_2⋅2⋅2)=(3⋅2⋅2)
\\9&(15)&(X_3⋅3)=(5⋅3)
\\10&(14),(15)&(X_5⋅2)=(7⋅2),(X_2⋅5)=(3⋅5)
\\11&13
\\12&(18),(20)&(X_2⋅6)=(3⋅6),(X_3⋅4)=(5⋅4)
\\13&17
\\14&(21),(22)&(X_2⋅7)=(3⋅7),(X_7⋅2)=(11⋅2)
\\15&(21),(25)&(X_5⋅3)=(7⋅3),(X_3⋅5)=(5⋅5)
\\16&(24)&(X_8⋅2)=(12⋅2),(X_4⋅4)=(6⋅4)
\\17&19
\\18&(27),(30)&(X_2⋅9)=(3⋅9),(X_3⋅6)=(5⋅6)
\\19&23
\\20&(30),(28)&(X_2⋅10)=(3⋅10),(X_4⋅5)=(6⋅5),(X_5⋅4)=(7⋅4)
\\.&.&.
\\.&.&.
\\.&.&.
\end{matrix}$$

*(The parenthesis are meant to distinguish composite numbers).

The idea is:

$a$ is just the sequence of positive integers.

For $X_a$: Starting with $X_1=1$ (as an exception), the following $X_a$ has the value of the nearest odd positive integer that is prime and wasn't mentioned earlier, unless $a$ is a composite.

That makes  $X_2=3$, $X_3=5$.

If $a$ is a composite, $X_a$  is composed based on the factors of $a$, which results in a set that can have multiple distinct values.

$$
d(a)=\{m∈N:m | a\}
$$

$d(a)$ is the set of all factors $m$ that divide $a$.

$$X_a=\{\forall m\in d(a): \frac{a}{m}⋅X_m\}$$.

(the $m$ in $X_m$ is a value for the arbitrary $a$ in $X_a$ such that for that specific value $X_{a=m}$).

For example:

The factors of $a=4$ are $2$ (besides $1$), $X_2=3$, and finally $2⋅X_2=2⋅3=6$.

Another Example:

The factors of $a=6$ are $2$ and $3$ (besides $1$), $X_2=3$ and $X_3=5$, and finally $X_6=X_3⋅2=5⋅2=10$ and $X_6=X_2⋅3=3⋅3=9$.

Observation:

Reminder: When $a$ is a prime number, $X_a$ will also be a prime.

This $X_a$ prime number will have a value that is: $\max(X_{a+1})>X_a > a$.

$\max(X_{a+1})$ means the highest distinct value for $(X_{a+1})$.

Examples:

$\max(X_{2+1})> X_2 >2 = \max(5)>3>2 = 5>3>2$.

$\max(X_{3+1})>X_3 >3 = \max(6)>5>3 = 6>5>3$.

$\max(X_{5+1})> X_5 >5 = \max(9,10)>7>5=10>7>5$.

The reason why I am encouraged by this observation has to do with the fact that:

If $a$ is a composite and the nearest smaller prime to it will be $p$, then $a$ can appear as $X_y=a$ when $y<p$.

(the $y$ in $X_y$ is a replacement value for the arbitrary $a$ in $X_a$ where in that specific value$X_{a=y}$).

Example: $a=9$, smaller nearest prime $p=7$, $X_y=X_6=9$, $y=6<p=7$.

Which raises another potential conjecture that can be related:

Let $p_i$ be the set of prime numbers greater than $3$ and let $i$ be the index numbers. Between each $X_{p_{i}}$ and $X_{p_{i-1}}$, there will be an $X_c$ that has a greater value than $p_i$

($i$,$i-1$, and $c$, are values for the the arbitrary $a$ in $X_a$)

Example:

Let $p_2$ be the 2nd element in the set of prime numbers greater  or equal to $3$, which is equal to $5$. that means that $p_{2-1}=3$.

Between $X_{p_{2}}=X_5=7$ and $X_{p_{1}}=X_3=5$, you have an $X_c=X_4 =6$, and $ X_c=X_4=6>p_2=5$

Does the above observation hold as a conjecture? and can it be proved?

*Any answers in regard to the second potential conjecture are also appreciated.

Comment: Could be interesting, but a bit hard to understand how exactly $X_n$ is defined. How far have you checked your conjecture/observation ?

Comment: Isn't the implication a prime $\implies$ $X_a$ prime clear by the definition (next number that is prime) ?

Comment: Finally, you get two disctint values for $X_6$ , hence $X_6$ does not seem to be well-defined.

Comment: @Peter I tried to address all of your comments with my modifications.

Comment: @Peter I also added a few more rows to demonstrate the likelihood of the conjecture.

Comment: You should define the function before the table

Comment: @Clyde Kertzer I can define a function if $a$ is a composite number , but if $a$ is a prime: it has to do with  picking a value for $X_a$ that is the first odd prime number that hasn't occurred before. I don't know how to do it.